# What does apt-get do?

Tags: apt, package-management

What exactly does `apt` do for us? More specifically what does it mean when someone says it manages package dependencies? Does this mean that if I am installing *PackageA* but *PackageA* requires *PackageA1*,*PackageA2*,*PackageA3*, and *PackageA4*. Then `apt` will download these for me?

Also does `apt` look for errors when downloading a package using the `checksum`??

I fail to see how this is a duplicate, so if someone can explain why that'd be great. The linked 'duplicate question' asks specifically about `apt-get update/upgrade` however there is far more to `apt` then just `apt-get update` such as `apt-get install/remove/purge` or `apt-cache ...`

Comment: Apt/apt-get are front ends for the real `dpkg` tool that does the install. `dpkg` however can only used already downloaded files, so yes, `apt` will download (as long as you have a source for the required pacakage), and yes it does verify the package is correctly signed & matches fingerprint.  Apt though has many functions; it can `update` repo lists (update), perform `upgrade` (within a set of rules), perform `full-upgrade` (fewer rules & more 'intelligent' than simple upgrade) etc...  refer to the documentation.

Comment: Have a look at the package python (assuming 18.04, https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python).  You'll note a lot of 'depends', ie. you can't install python until they've already been installed. `dpkg` requires they be installed at the same time, or already be installed. `apt` will check they are installed, and if not attempt download & then install...

Comment: ps: i didn't down-vote, but I suspect you were down-voted because the question lacked a feel of doing any homework  (and not just 'duplicate')

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will admit I probably didn't search around as hard as I could, but I really didn't find any great explanations on dependency management,

Comment: Here's some reading material: https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.apt-get.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apt/apt-get are front ends for the real tools that do the work.  `dpkg` for example can't download, and requires all dependencies (*deps*) be already installed, or installed at the same time.  Apt/apt-get will look to see if all required dependencies are installed, and if not download them, installing them too.

Yes `apt` does verify the package is correctly signed & was downloaded correctly.

`apt` has many functions; it can update repo lists (`update`), perform `upgrade` (within a set of rules), perform `full-upgrade` (fewer rules & more 'intelligent' than simple upgrade) and more. Refer to the documentation (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/apt.8.html).

**With regard dependencies.**

As an example, the package `python`'  (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python).

You'll note a lot of 'depends' including `python2.7`, `python-minimal` and more. ie. you can't install (using `dpkg`) python until all 'depends' are  already installed. `apt` will check for this, then if not already installed it will attempt download (*I used attempt as the packages must exist in your repository list sources*) & then install, plus your requested package.